# how to use datehelper methods with view

Tags: date, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I am using date helper method for converting datetime into my helper class...

But i have result like for all date to "a moment ago" only. It takes only the system date not from model.. please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in partial view Model.Helpers.DateHelper.GetFriendlyDate(DateTime.Now). so it takes current date..

You put like this,

```
<%var createdDate =  Dial4Jobz.Helpers.DateHelper.GetFriendlyDate((DateTime)ViewData["CreatedDate"]); %>
```